# Missing tilde in the 'People Reached' stat

Tags: discussion, profile-page, people-reached

Is the 'people reached' calculation on the Profile -> Stats section meant to not have the tilde character `~` as it is showing in the Profile -> Activity -> Impact area?

Based on the mouse hover for info behind these calcs, the same definition is shown to the user.

There are a number of questions/posts around the calc behind this data point and this is not what this question is, it is just regarding the display.

Is this more of a design decision because it allows the user to quickly glance at their stats without checking the 'Activity' area's Impact box?

**Stats**
[image]

Comment: Reported here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368304/756727